# Node JS Sequelize ORM date issue

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am using sequelize ORM of node js to connect to mysql database.

I am having a field named **"dob (date of birth)"** that is of type **date**.

When I am storing any value in that field it is storing properly, but while fetching it is giving one date less than the one that is there in the database.

For example, I am storing **"1990-10-27"** in the database and while fetching it is returning me **"Fri Oct 26 1990 18:30:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)"**.

Can anybody please help me with this.

Comment: Please show us your code. [I tried, but I cannot reproduce this problem](https://gist.github.com/alexbooker/4900b3cfc284cab0510ca17088fbfcc5). It could be environmental.

Comment: Maybe you should check your timezone

Comment: @Martial: In the configuration itself I have mentioned the timezone as "+05:30" as I want the timezone to be in IST.

Comment: @AlexBooker: I am fetching the field through "find" method of sequelize on my model which is giving me one date less than the actual value. This is happening for all the date fields of the database tables.

Comment: Have you noticed that the time returned is exactly 5:30 earlier than the correct value?

Comment: DATE create a DATETIME field in database. Maybe you should define your field as DATEONLY instead.

Comment: @Martial: I have defined the field as DATEONLY

Comment: without your code it will be hard to help you more

Comment: What version of Node are you using?

Comment: I removed from my sequelize configuration the "timezone" option and it resolved my issue.